# Error while filtering the Cache Data : Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**I am trying to filter the cache data using the below code**

```
$Categories = \Cache::rememberForever('Categories', function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
});

$Category = $Categories::where("CategoryID", "=", $id)->first();
```

**Error details :**

> Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

**Am I missing anything ?**

I meant, what's the fastest way to filter the data in cache object. Cache object is a Model. Categories Array contains collection of Models that contains categoryID ID. and I want to filter data based on CategoryID

Comment: Is your `$Categories` variable a `Collection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$Categories->where("CategoryID", $id)->first();
// or
$Categories->where("CategoryID", '=', $id)->first();
```

`where` cannot be called staticly. Checkout class `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

**Edit:**

You can only call it static on a Eloquent model, in the way you tried. And because you fetched the results already (into Collection).

Comment: When I do above I don't get any filtered record. Whereas I am able to get record when I write `for each` loop

Comment: How does the array/data structure look like?